# how do I test hiera values in puppet testing

Tags: puppet, serverspec

I have below manifests in puppet:

```
class env {
    $line = hiera('LINE')

    file { '/opt/dt/LINE' 
        ensure  => file,
        owner   => 'root',
        group   => 'root',
        mode    => '0644',
        content => "${line}\n",
    }
}
```

I want to write serverspec for this, but do we have an option in serverspec to pass Hiera value like how we pass Hiera value in rspec-puppet test case.

I tried browsing for an serverspec Hiera example but no luck :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created '.yml' file under root of the module and added below lines in '_spec.rb' file and it worked :)

```
require 'yaml' 

tmp = YAML.load_file 'pack.yml'
 tmp.each do|a|
    describe package(a) do
      it { should be_installed }
```